# Using the VALUES-clause in a SELECT statement with MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

In MS Access, is it possible to use the `VALUES` clause inside a `SELECT` statement? For example:

```
SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES(1)) AS FOOBAR
```

This works with DB2, but when trying to execute the above statement in MS Access 2010 it highlights the word `VALUES` and pops up a message box saying *"Syntaxerror in FROM clause"*.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but if it is "No", then another way to construct an "in-place" table (which MS Access also might not support...) is with `UNION ALL`: `SELECT ... FROM (SELECT 'r1c1', 'r1c2' UNION ALL SELECT 'r2c1', 'r2c2' UNION ALL SELECT 'r3c1', 'r3c2' ...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand correctly, the `values` statement in DB2 gives you the possibility to create rows on the fly.

This is not possible in many other platforms using the `values` keyword.

This is the only possible solution using Access:

```
select 1 foo
union
all
select 2
```

This works on DB2:

```
select 1 foo
from   sysdummy1
union
all
select 2
from   sysdummy1
```

You could fake this behavior in Access by creating a dummy table called `sysdummy1` and adding one row to it.

Comment: Not too bad, but is there anything that might work on both platforms? I need this for a wrapper which is supposed to work with both, DB2 and MS Access and I'd prefer not to have different statements depending on the platform it's being executed on.

Comment: See the updated answer. There is a workaround available for that.

Comment: The `VALUES (..), (..), ...(..)` syntax is called **["table value constructor"](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-training/table-value-constructors-in-sql-server-2008/)**. It's standard SQL and available in SQL-Server (2008+) and Postgres as well.

Comment: @ypercube: I didn't know that. Thanks for the info. I am using Oracle mostly and it doesn't work there :(